# Piping multilpe times using unary operator

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I have the following function:

```
Function Refine{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
          $data
        )
        begin {}
        process {
            For ($i=0; $i -le $data.count; $i++){
            if ($data[$i] -match 'nmap scan report' -and $data[$i+1] -match 'host is up' )  {
                $dat += $data[$i] + "`n"
                $counter=($i+4)
                while ($data[$counter] -match '^[0-9]') {
                    $dat += $data[$counter] + "`n"
                    $counter++
                }        
                }
            }
            
         }
        end { 
            if ($dat){#See that its not empty
            return  $dat.Split([Environment]::NewLine)
            }
        }
    }

$file1 = gc c:\test.txt

,gc ($file1) | Refine
```

I must pipe with the Unary operator since i want the whole object to be piped at one time to the Refine Function.

The output is something like this for example:
Nmap scan report for 1.1.1.1
113/tcp closed ident
443/tcp open   ssl/http Fortinet SSL VPN
Nmap scan report for 2.2.2.2
21/tcp  filtered ftp
22/tcp  filtered ssh

I now would like to use the another function which takes this and create objects from text:

```
  Function BuildArray{
      [CmdletBinding()]
      Param(
          [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
          $data
      )
      Begin {}
      Process {
        $NMAPS=@()
        $nmap=@()
        $ports=@()
        For ($i=0; $i -lt $data.count; $i++){
            If ($data[$i] -match 'nmap scan report')  {
            $ip = ($data[$i] |  Select-String -Pattern "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" -AllMatches).Matches.Value
            $k=$i
            If ($data[($i+1)] -notmatch 'nmap scan report' -and $i -le $data.count){
                DO{
                $ports+=$data[$i+1]
                $i++
                }
               While ($data[$i+1] -notmatch 'nmap scan report' -and $i -le $data.count)
               $nmap = @{IP = "$ip"; ports=@($ports)}
               $NMAPS+=$nmap
               $nmap=@()
               $ports=@()
               $i = $k
               }
              }
            }
      }
      End {
        $NMAPS
      }
  }
```

My problem here is again - i would like the data from the pipe to pass as a whole to the BuildArray function. but i cannot use the unary operator since i get an error saying i can use it only at the start of the piping,

```
 ,(gc $file1 ) | ,(refine) | BuildArray #No good
```

How Can i pass this second object in the pipline as a whole to the third object once at once?

Comment: `Write-Output (gc $file1) -NoEnumerate` as the initial expression, then use `Write-Output $output -NoEnumerate` instead of `return` inside your functions

Comment: Maybe `, ( , (gc $file1 ) | refine) | BuildArray` ?

Comment: So you want the first and second combined into one object and passed as a whole to BuildArray?

Comment: I Actually want first to read from a file using Get-Content then pipe it to a function that changes the text to the way i like (Refine) and pipe it to a function that take the text and build an custom object from that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all respect, you are not on the right track with the general concept of the [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7). Cmdlets should [implement for the Middle of a Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines?view=powershell-7#implement-for-the-middle-of-a-pipeline), meaning that each cmdlet should process each item a.s.a.p. and *stream* it onto the next cmdlet to eventually release it from memory.
A PowerShell object ([PSCustomObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7)) is optimized for streaming as it contains all type information of its properties. This makes these PowerShell objects heavy and less suitable for storing them in a (large) collection.
Specific to your own functions, it makes your [input processing methods](https://learn.microsoft.com//powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7#input-processing-methods) (the `Start`, `Process` and `End` block structure) pointless which is especially developed to [`Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7#process) *each specific object* in the pipeline. If you collect all your objects in an array before passing it to your `BuildArray` function, you might as well just use the [`End`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7#end) block (*or leave all the input blocks which is similar to just an `End` block*) where the [automated `$Input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) holds *all the objects supplied in the pipeline* in a single array:

```
Function BuildArray {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$data
    )
    Process { Write-Host 'Process:' $Input }
}

1,2,3 | BuildArray

Process: 1
Process: 2
Process: 3
```

```
Function BuildArray {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$data
    )
    End { Write-Host 'End:' $Input } # or just: Write-Host $Input
}

1,2,3 | BuildArray

End: 1 2 3
```

Also:

- [Try I avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a
  collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) (or a string) as it is
  exponential expensive.

  - And if you do use it, you should properly initialize the `$dat = ''` value otherwise you might start with an unexpected copy inherited from one of it parents functions.